# HTML div becomes hidden when including jqueryUI.js when using JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have an issue when I include JQueryUI.js to my php code. I have a mobile site that applies the following CSS

```
.ui-mobile [data-role="page"], .ui-mobile [data-role="dialog"], .ui-page {
    border: 0 none;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

when I include JQueryUI.js. My template is

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mobile.css" />
    <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script> 

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png"  href="/images/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
   <div data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="mpage">

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="c" id="mheader">
            <?php echo $this->partial('mheader.phtml'); ?>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" data-theme="c" id="mcontent">  
            <?php echo $this->layout()->content ?>  
        </div>

        <br/><br/>

        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c" id="mfooter">
            <?php echo $this->partial('mfooter.phtml'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>



</body>
```

and when I check the style on firebug I see the following div disappear

```
<div id="mpage" data-theme="c" data-role="page" data-url="mpage">
```

Comment: i don't understand the issue you're having. could you state the question clearer?

Comment: Sorry about that... I am developing a form that uses jquery. I need to include the jqueryUI.js but whenever I do the whole page becomes invisible. When i dont include jqueryUI.js the pages shows up fine but ofcourse i wont be able to use the jqueryUI actions. The CCS in the body of the question is getting applied for some reason and the page becomes invisible.. i hope this is explaining the question better... thank you

Comment: It worked with a different version of JQuery-ui

Answer (score 2):

It worked by using a different version of jquery-ui